# In columns [1, 2, 3, ...] make UNIQUE between [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), ...]

Tags: mysql, sql, unique

Basically the title.

What would be considered better:

1. n-1 UNIQUE pairs between all (1, k) columns
2. Some trigger that basically does the same as above, but then again - how to do it without tons of code.
3. Other unknown to me short way - please point me in right direction.

As to making example out of this:

Say there is a Product that has many Attributes. We want all columns in Attribute to be unique for Product, so for example:

```
Product
ID    Name
1     Something
2     Other

Attribute
ID    ProductID  Name    Code    Alias1    Alias2
1     1          One     O       1         |
2     1          Two     T       2         ||
3     1          Three   T       3         |||
4     2          Two     T       2         ||
```

So Attribute with ID=4 passes because it is unique on all columns for ProductID=2. Attribute ID=3 will fail because it repeats Code=T already used by ID=2.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a separate unique constraint on each pair of columns with `productid`:

```
create unique index unq_product_productid_name on product(productid, name);
create unique index unq_product_productid_code on product(productid, code);
create unique index unq_product_productid_alias1 on product(productid, alias1);
create unique index unq_product_productid_alias1 on product(productid, alias2);
```

You *could* implement this using a trigger.  However, determining uniqueness is going to be rather expensive, unless you have an index on each column pair.  So, for performance, you would want the same indexes.

There is overhead to having these indexes -- particularly on data modification operations.  If you do this only very rarely, then a trigger without indexes might be okay.

In balance, though, I would go for the separate unique indexes on each pair, because that is the *intent* of your data integrity checks.  Start with code that cleanly expresses your intent.  Later you can work on alternative solutions if performance is an issue.

Comment: Thanks for reassurance that doing separate unique pairs is (not bad) way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `UNIQUE` index on both columns:

```
CREATE INDEX UQ_tab ON tab_name(ProductId, Code);
-- before you do that you need to clean initial data
```

Comment: So basically my (1). Problem is that when u have more than few such pairs, you get n-1 such UNIQUEs. Now imagine table with 20 UNIQUEs. Also yes - there is a very specific reason why I do it this way.